# Negative one to the power of two question - i.e. (-1)**2

Tags: python, algebra

Can someone explain the difference between these two expressions in Python:

```
(-1)**2 == 1
-1**2 == -1
```

Why do the parentheses change the outcome?

Comment: Double check the operator precedence of the unary `-` and `**` operators.

Comment: Python first calculates the power according to operator precedence and then the -

Comment: This is a math question, not for coding.

Comment: Both equations yield 1 as the result on a calculator. As other answers have shown, it's because of the way python completes the ** operator and then interprets the - after.         Thus this is a python question.

Comment: See documentation on [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses means the whole value inside is will be raised to the power `2`.

```
(-1)**2 == 1
```

So `-1*-1` is `1`
No parentheses means the `-` will  be taken out of the equation and added to the end of the answer.

```
1) -1**2
2) 1**2 
3) 1
4) -1
```

Python handles this the same way the world does :)